Swapping CANH and CANL kills my power converter
I got the first set of these CAN boards I designed and I plugged one into my test setup consisting of a two CAN dev boards as seen below. The first time I plugged my board in I didn't realize I had CANH and CANL swapped and my SMPS (U2) failed (V_BATTERY shorted, chip overheats). At this point I noticed CANH and CANL were swapped and corrected them. I replaced U2 and plugged everything back in and it all worked fine. Trying to determine what was the cause of U2 failing was, I swapped CANH and CANL again so they were backwards and again, U2 input failed short and heats up. If I power the 5V rail on my board with a power supply and swap CANH and CANL the power supply doesn't short and I can't find any signs of anything else bad happening.
Does anyone have any thoughts as to what is going on here? Even if not, is there anything I can do (within reason) regardless to increase the robustness of my circuit?
V_BATTERY in all places is a benchtop power supply set to 14.8V and a current limit of 500mA. Ground is common between my board, the test circuitry, and power supply.
Page 1 (Root)

Page 2 (Power Regulation)
Page 3 (CANbus) MCP2526 datasheet

Test circuitry connected to my board (dev board link)

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Link to MCP2562 datasheet?

Just swapping CANH and CANL won't damage anything. The reason is something else.

@winny MCP2562 and ADP2302 datasheet links added


U5. 5V and 3V3 doesn't seem connected to any other net. They should be connected as done with U4 or otherwise the IC will obviously not work and might get damaged.
U1. Why are there no caps? You need caps on input & output as per datasheet recommendations or the regulator might become unstable. It also doesn't hurt to place a larger bulk cap there, of a couple of hundred uF.


U5, they are. I labeled 3v3 and 5v locally on that sheet on U4 as well. Admittedly I can probably draw that better.
U1 is a TVS ESD protection array not a regulator. 5V_USB feed U3 which has input and output caps as specified for stability.

I concur. The diodes in the MCP2562 should block any such condition from breaking your board. Something else is up. Fake MCP2562? Something connected not as drawn? Floating supplies?

@AlexJegers U1 on the test board.

@winny To your point if the MCP2562 was fake and the diodes weren't blocking wouldn't that heat up/damage the MCP2562 as well? They're from Digikey so I'd be surprised if they're fake. I'll take a look at my board layout to make sure everything is connected as drawn but I'd expect DRC to catch it if not. By "floating supply" do you mean like a bad/missing ground? Would that potentially cause a short or over-voltage somewhere?

@AlexJegers Oh btw STBY is floating, it should be grounded. That's wrong.

@Lundin Ah, yes. Test board is on a breadboard, I have caps on there just didn't put them in this schematic. I figured that out about STBY, I have botch wires on them for now, thanks for pointing that out.

DK = 99.999 % genuine parts. Something else is the problem. Are both CAN devices on the same board? Floating supply = not shared ground.

@AlexJegers Breadboard = give me strange problems for the heck of it. Never use breadboards for any purpose. I don't see how you could even use one with SMD components anyway, even if you use the SO8 version of MCP2562.

@Lundin My circuit (page 1, 2, 3) as noted above is on a PCB. The "Test circuitry connected to my board" as noted above is on a breadboard. You're right about the breadboard problems, may be worth creating another PCB for the test circuitry...
